# Source files when opening an external terminal through Bash

Tags: bash, terminal, console, source, konsole

For a start up script I want to open multiple several terminal windows on an Ubuntu system and execute some commands in each.
Some of those commands require files to be loaded. Normally I do that with

```
$ source path/to/file.sh
```

and then call my

```
$ MY_COMMAND
```

However if I open a new console with:

```
konsole -e "source path/to/file.sh; MY_COMMAND"
```

I get an error that "source" is not an executable.
Have found out that "source" is in fact something built into the shell, but is there a way to achieve the same when opening an external terminal directly from bash?

Huge thanks :)

Comment: Probably something like `konsole -e 'shell-of-choice -c "source whatever; command"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the shell as the executable to be run by `konsole`:

```
konsole -e bash -c 'source path/to/file.sh; MY_COMMAND'
```

Now `konsole` knows what command to run (in this case `bash`), and the `-c` option with the commands are passed to `bash` to be run as its command input.